# Complex find in Ruby on Rails to match equivalent render

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm trying to do a `find` in Ruby on Rails that matches this `render`:

```
render :json => user.friendships.visible,
       :only => [],
       :include => [{:friend => {:except => [:password]}}, :status]
```

So basically get all friendships from a user that are visible, but with none of the association table.  I just want the friend object (except the password) and the status.  This works fine when rendering but I'm not sure how to do a `find` to get all the same info.  All I can ever get back are the friendships rows which just define the association.  I'm just trying to get these back and store them in a variable.  So I can't render them just yet.  Maybe `find` isn't what I'm looking for.

The `visible` property is a defined scope on `friendships`.

Comment: For really complex rendering, especially when you want to avoid leaking data, try [jbuilder](https://github.com/rails/jbuilder) to make proper JSON views.

Comment: The rendering works fine.  I'm just looking for the equivalent retrieval method.  I'm relatively new to ruby and rails.

Comment: I don’t know the answer myself, but the Rails guides [Active Record Query Interface](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html) and [Layouts and Rendering in Rails – Using `render`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#using-render) might help.

Comment: When I see things like `password` in the model, I'm usually terrified. You're not using plain-text passwords, are you?

Comment: Of course not, it's a salted sha1 hash.  I don't even think passwords are relevant at this point in the project, but I'd like to make sure they aren't output with the data in future updates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should return an array of the visible friends for a given user:

```
user.friendships.visible.includes(:friend).map(&:friend)
```

I'm writing this off the cuff without knowing exactly what your models look like, or what your use case is.

Comment: That does.  But I also need that status and to remove the password from the friend object. I've been trying to map the two variables appropriately but can't get the syntax right.  I've been trying something like this but to no avail.  `user.friendships.visible.includes(:friend, :status).map({"friend" => &:friend, "status" => &:status})`

Comment: Got that part working with this `friendsArr = user.friendships.visible.includes(:friend, :status).map {|f| {friend: f.friend, status: f.status}}`

Comment: Last issue is how to hide the password from the friend object

Comment: So I'm assuming/hoping the password is hashed and salted, but I'm having trouble understanding what the purpose behind removing it from the object is. If you are rendering it to json, you should be able to select the attributes you want at that point. Otherwise, you can add another line to your block and set f.password to nil, but thats feels janky.

Comment: I was just trying to remove it and some other things from the output.  Of course it's hashed and salted.  I'm just dumping a ton of data and for security and data length purposes I was just trying to strip some thing out.  The original rendering I used removed the proper things.  I'm just looking for the equivalent of :except in this context

Comment: I don't think there's a direct equivalent - you could use `select` to pick the individual fields you want to query from the db, or you could call `to_json` with basically the same settings as in your render call.